# how to encrypt a text file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, encryption

How can i encrypt the content in a text file using batch? and how can i decrypt it?

i have tried setting each letter to a number but i do not know how to split the string into each letter and do that.

I watched a video on youtube that help turn letters into numbers but it did not do it with a file.

this is the code he provides in the video.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p code=Text:
set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "code=!code:%%C=%%N!"

)

)

echo !code! 
pause
```

Please help Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SET    abet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#-/\ .0123456789
SET cipher1=8p#j4 9z\6w.ae@0u2r5o!xk-cf1b3g7hmqil/sntdvy
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20794050.txt) DO (
  SET line=%%a
  CALL :encipher
 )
)>q20794050.txt.1
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20794050.txt.1) DO (
  SET line=%%a
  CALL :decipher
 )
)>q20794050.txt.2
GOTO :EOF
:decipher
SET morf=%abet%
SET from=%cipher1%
GOTO trans
:encipher
SET from=%abet%
SET morf=%cipher1%
:trans
SET "enil="
:transl
SET $1=%from%
SET $2=%morf%
:transc
IF /i "%line:~0,1%"=="%$1:~0,1%" SET enil=%enil%%$2:~0,1%&GOTO transnc
SET $1=%$1:~1%
SET $2=%$2:~1%
IF DEFINED $2 GOTO transc
:: No translation - keep
SET enil=%enil%%line:~0,1%
:transnc
SET line=%line:~1%
IF DEFINED line GOTO transl
ECHO %enil%
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a way to do it using a simple Cæsar (substitution) code.

`abet` can be set (possibly from a file) to the set of characters that you want to encode. Similarly, `cipher1` can be set to the transled set - just make sure that each character in `abet` also appears in `cipher1`.

Any character that appears in the input text but not in `abet` will not be translated.

I used `q20794050.txt`:

```
The quick brown fox [jumps] {over} the lazy dog 9876543210.
9876543210 The quick brown fox !@#-/\ jumps over the lazy dog.f
```

Which was encoded to `q20794050.txt.1` :

```
5z4huo\#whp2@xeh @kh[6oa0r]h{@!42}h5z4h.8c-hj@9hyvdtns/liqm
yvdtns/liqh5z4huo\#whp2@xeh @khf1b3g7h6oa0rh@!42h5z4h.8c-hj@9m
```

(Note that there is a <kbd>Space</kbd> at the end of that last line...)

And was successfully disencrypted to `q20794050.txt.2`

Note: the above won't handle certain problem characters like %&|><

I've only used lower-case so any upper-case would be translated to lower-case by the process. If you remove the `/i` from the `IF` statement, then case will be preserved, but you'd have to add the upper-case letters to `abet` and `cipher1` else the encrypted file will contain the upper-case characters verbatim.

Note that

```
(for...do (...))>somefilename
```

will create a new file `somefilename` containing any data `ECHO`ed - even if the `ECHO` occurs in a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%h in ('type %1') do (
set text=%%h 
)

set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "text=!text:%%C=-%%N!"

)

)

echo !text! > %userprofile%\Desktop\encrypted.txt
pause


(using a different .bat file)

@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%h in ('type %1') do (
set text=%%h 
)

set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "text=!text:%%N=%%C!"

)

)

for /f %%K in ("!text!") do (
set "text=!text:-=!"
)

echo !text! > %userprofile%\Desktop\decrypted.txt
pause
```